# Aggregation With Golang/Mongodb Gives Error "Missing type in composite literal"

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I am trying to get users in a certain age range via aggregation.

**Edit:** I am able to work through mongo shell, query works fine however I am not able to make it work with go

> This code gives me "missing type in composite literal" error.

What am I missing here?

```
lte := 10
gte := 0

operations := []bson.M{
    {
        "$match":{
            "$and":[]interface{}{
                bson.M{"age":{"$gte":gte}},
                bson.M{"age":{"$lte":lte}},
            },
        },
    },
    {
        "$group":bson.M{"_id":"$user_id"},
    },

}

r := []bson.M{}

pipe := c.Pipe(operations)
err := pipe.All(&r)
if err != nil {
    logrus.Errorf("Error:  %v", err)
    return err
}
```

Comment: you are grouping by user_id but I don't see where you are selecting that as a result value

Comment: Please add an example document [by editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36142981/edit).

Comment: @obi1 I am not sure I understand, can you elaborate ?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, My question arises due to the fact that this code does not compile. I am not sure why you need an example document here.

Comment: @ceroloy Simply to make sure you actually _do have_ a field named `user_id` and to prevent lengthy discussions. ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Oh ok, I am able to work through mongo shell, query works fine however I am not able to make it work with go.

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined "each" pipeline stage as a `bson.M`. It's an "array" of `bson.M`, hence the error:

```
operations := []bson.M{
    bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "date": bson.M{ "$gte": gte, "$lte": lte }
        }
    },
    bson.M{
        "group": bson.M{ "_id": "$user_id" }
    }
}
```

Also [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is not necessary. **ALL** MongoDB query conditions are already an "AND" expression anyway. The combination of [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) as keys in the same object expression is *already* an AND condtion on the same `"date"` property. Just as would be the addition of more keys within the `$match` object.

In the JavaScript shell, this is the same as:

```
var operations = [
    { "$match": { "date": { "$gte": gte, "$lte": lte } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$user_id" } }
];
```

So you need to remember that every JavaScript object notation `{}` equals a `.bson.M{}` statement. That's how you notate BSON objects in go with this libary.

**Note:** `{ "$group": { "_id": "$user_id } }` is not going to do anything meaningful other than just return each "distinct" `"user_id"` value. So you likely want more [accumulator options](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/) in any real result

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I am trying to get distinct users in the given age range that is why I used group? Is that a mistake too?

Comment: @cemre The question you asked was about was about a composite literal with the expression you had. I gave you a solution that solved this. I have also rolled back your question revision as that is extremely rude. This is not a threaded discussion. You ask a question and someone answers it, then you accept it an move on. If you have other questions then [Ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Do not change your questions here from what you originally ask. People are nice enough to answer, so be nice back.

Comment: In addition, no your answer did not solved my problem since you modified the conditional part. I was originally trying to learn about using conditionals in the query and your answer just removes the part I am trying to learn.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
operations := []bson.M{
    bson.M{
        "$match":bson.M{
            "$and":[]interface{}{
                bson.M{"age":bson.M{"$gte":gte}},
                bson.M{"age":bson.M{"$lte":lte}},
            },
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "$group":bson.M{"_id":"$user_id"},
    },

}
```

You simply forgot bson.M before "$and".

**Edit**: Looks like the ages too, I went ahead and fixed those.

**Edit2**: I missed more bson.M's than the initial 3 missing that I saw.

Comment: It missed more than just one `bson.M`, This again would simply not compile, as well as not noting that the `$and` is completely unnecessary